Navigating d3-flame-graph in a VSCode Webview panel using keypresses (w a s d / arrow keys) on keyboard
I have a VSCode extension that displays a flame graph in a Webview. Are there any recommended ways to navigate the flame graph using arrow keys on the keyboard, similar to how a user would navigate a flame graph in chrome dev tools ?
